# iterating dictionary and fetching values from inner dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator

am trying to build a logic which am not quit sure how to do with python. I have the following dictionary

```
{datetime.datetime(2011, 7, 18, 13, 59, 25): (u'hello-world', u'hello world'), datetime.datetime(2011, 7, 17, 15, 45, 54): (u'mazban-archeticture', u'mazban arch'), datetime.datetime(2011, 7, 7, 15, 51, 49): (u'blog-post-1', u'blog post 1'), datetime.datetime(2011, 7, 8, 15, 54, 5): (u'blog-post-2', u'blog post 2'), datetime.datetime(2011, 7, 18, 15, 55, 32): (u'blog-post-3', u'blog post 3')}
```

I want to iterate through the dictionary, find out if the date is equal today's date and then use the inner dictionary to build a url using the first value as a slug. Am able to iterate but I don't know how to fetch the inner value

```
# will only print dates
for i in dic:
 print i
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In python when you use 'for x in dic' it is the same as to use 'for x in dic.keys()' - you are iterating trough only keys not (key,value) pairs. 
To do what you want you can take a look at the [items()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict.items) and [iteritems()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict.iteritems) dictionary methods, they allows you to get access to (key,value) pairs:

```
for key,value in dic.iteritems():
    if key == datetime.today(): # or (datetime.today() - key).seconds == <any value you expect>
        # since value is a tuple(not a dict) and you want to get the first item you can use index 0
        slug = value[0]
```

Read more about [dictionaries and supported methods](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the value then you subscript the dictionary, unless you actually want tuples this is usually less hassle than using either `.items()` or `.iteritems()` methods:

```
for i in dic:
 print i, dic[i]
```

BTW, you say 'inner dictionary' but you only have one dictionary, the values are tuples.